# Is it possible that, not closing DB connections to be the reason for heap overflow in Java on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I wrote a web application with java and mysql. And now every week I need to restart the tomcat. Otherwise it gives an error like this:

> "Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: You haven't really even given enough information to determine that your problem is related to heap overflow. Do you have stack traces? Heap dumps? Any reason to suspect that your error is open connections? Anything seem to run differently before it dies? Have you tried altering the memory settings? A bit more information, please.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a lot of things. I would recommend running [jmap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) to dump the heap, and then analyze using [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). I've found this extremely useful in cases where heap grows up over a period of time. The tool will tell you the leak suspect and you can narrow down your case. If you notice that you've too many connection objects lying around that cannot be garbage collected, that right there is the problem. At the same time, there is a good chance that you'd end up finding another leak suspects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, neglecting to close database connections (or files, or network connections) is one possible source of this. There are many others of course!